# How to begin writing a python wrapper around another wrapper?

Tags: python, couchdb, wrapper

I know this question has been asked by one or two people but it's somehow different from what I have in mind.  Please bear with me.

I'm trying to write a wrapper around the existing couchdb-python wrapper.  The reason for this is that in the event that we decide to switch to another NoSQL database in the future, for example MongoDB, I only have to change one part of my codebase.

Question 1:  Is this the suggested right course of action given the above scenario?

The problem with accessing couchdb using the couchdb-python wrapper, sometimes (not all the time), a username/password is required to access the database.  This is what it looks like in code:

```
server = Server()   <---- When no username/password is required
server = Server('http://abc:123@localhost:5984')  <---- When username/password is required
```

How would I define the inital **init** function to cater for both scenarios.  I have somehting like this at the moment:

```
from couchdb import Server


class Couch(object):
    """ CouchDB Wrapper """
    COUCHDB_URI = {username_not_provided: 'http://localhost:5984',
                   username_provided: 'http://%s:%s@localhost:5984'}
    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None):
        if username and password:
            self.url = COUCHDB_URI['username_provided'] % (username, password)
        else:
            self.url = COUCHDB_URI['username_not_provided']
        self.server = Server(self.url)
```

I think the code looks ugly, can someone point me in the right direction for the above?

Thank you everyone!  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is building off of larsmans answer to your specific formatting question, but I think you might want to go about it a different way than this. It might be better to first create a Base class that defines a common interface for any of your NoSQL backends. Something like this:

```
class Database(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.connect(**kwargs)

    def connect(self, **kwargs):
        pass


class Couch(Database):

    def __init__(**kwargs):
        super(Couch, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def connect(self, username=None, password=None):
        if username and password:
            # connect this way
            pass
        else:
            # connect that way
            pass
```

Database class would define all the interface methods that subclasses should implement. That way your higher level code can assume a common Database object, and you would just need to define new modules for different NoSQL backends.

**Edit**

You should take a look at nonrel django: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel

They are accomplishing this same task for django, using mongodb as their primary choice, but you would be able to add more support by implementing a few of their base classes for CouchDB. This should give you a good idea of how they accomplish it, since django is the same idea, using an agnostic ORM layer over swappable database backends.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
class Couch(object):
    URI_TEMPLATE = "http://%slocalhost:5984"

    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None):
        if username and password:
            user_part = "%s:%s@" % (username, password)
        else:
            user_part = ""
        self.url = URI_TEMPLATE % user_part
```

although the downside here is that the `%s` doesn't stand out in the URI template.

It's not going to get much prettier than this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I was really looking for a combination of your answer and JDI's answer.  I wonder if it's possible to award point to both of you.